Ubuntu 24.04 Nautilus does not show the progress disc when copying large amount of files
I noticed that Nautilus in Ubuntu 24.04 does not show the progress disc when copying a large amount of files. Is this situation unique to me or is there a bug or this feature has been removed? Nautilus in Ubuntu 22.04 does show this copying progress disc.
Reply to @cordlord answer:
The image below illustrates what I meant in my comment to your answer. The benefit of this approach over the use of multiple tabs in one window is that the contents in both folders are simultaneously visible.

This next image shows the menu bar when the nautilus window is not in a compact mode. As you have mentioned in your answer, the copying progress info is shown at the bottom of the left menu bar.


It's still there but it has been moved - it now shows at the far bottom-left corner.

This change is problematic. When using multiple Nautilus windows, its left menu sidebar is hidden. Consequently, the new copying progress info is also hidden. That is why I could not see it.

Not quite sure what you mean about it being hidden, but personally I tend to use the tab functionality rather than multiple windows anyway.

I have added images to my question to illustrate what I mean. Yes, this change seems to benefit using multiple tabs in a single window to copy multiple files vs using multiple windows to do the same.

o.k. I see what you mean now - if you reduce the width of a Nautilus window enough the left sidebar disappears. Although with a 1920x1080 16:9 monitor at 100% scaling I can still have 2 nautilus windows open with the sidebars visible. I have to reduce the width of the window to about one-third of the screen width before it goes into the compact mode.

The issue occurs for laptops. They have a smaller screen size than a standard monitor.

Screen size has no bearing, it's about resolution and screen scaling factor
